# Ajax Unobtrusive render partial Error dont show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im try render in a div one partial but this is not render, the error is this:

```
Started GET "/user/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Jan 15 19:33:17 -0200 2013
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.4ms)
```

im dont know what is wrong, im try use this:

<%= link_to "Editar perfil", edit_user_path(current_user), :remote => true %>

the problem is not change when i click, i make the

edit.js.erb

```
$("#adm_content").html("<%= render :partial =>'users/edit' %>");
```

but not happening im see the routes and is correct:

```
 new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)                         user#new
edit_user GET    /user/:id/edit(.:format)                    user#edit
     user GET    /user/:id(.:format)                         user#show
```

what is wrong when I click appear the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks im consert changing the name of the routes of singular to plurar, :user to :users, thanks.

Comment: Correct, its users are correct, very thanks im solve but is it i make hehe =D thanks a lot man.